# Tengo este codigo pero me genera este error al crear el pdf que une los otros

Tags: c#, pdf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro el codigo que utilizo y el pantallazo que me arroja cuando intento abrir el pdf.

[image: c#]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, pues después de varios intentos y verificando todo por todo lado ese código siempre me arroja que es un pdf dañado, seguí investigando y encontré este enlace pues es un poco mas largo el código pero si me funciono hasta el momento

http://jbautistam.com/Articulos/Utilidades/Combinar-PDF.htm

Agradezco si alguien sabe como arreglar el código de la pregunta muchas gracias.